# link task depending on content

Tags: regex, ansible

I have 3 tasks..

first task checks if a file contains `<ip> <hostname>` pattern

second task adds a line if the sought after string is not present.

third task corrects the line if it is bad.

the 3 tasks run well independently but I want to run them together somehow linked.

I have the following playbook using as model /etc/hosts.

```
---
- name: check hosts playbook
  hosts: centos

  tasks:

  - name: check whether a line in the form of '<ip> <hostname>' exists
    lineinfile:
      path: /var/tmp/hosts
      regexp: '^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s\w+'
      state: absent
    check_mode: true
    register: line_exists

  - name: append_host_file 
    lineinfile:
      path: /var/tmp/hosts
      insertafter: '^(127\.0\.0\.1|)(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}'
      line: '{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }} {{ansible_hostname }}'
      backup: yes
    when: not line_exists.changed

  - name: correct_hosts_file
    lineinfile:
     path: /var/tmp/hosts
     regexp: '^(?!{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}\s{{ ansible_hostname }})(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\s\w+'
     line: '{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }} {{ansible_hostname }}'
    when: line_exists.changed
```

the issue i have is the correct task is running when the line is correct.. so i need to use some other sort of criteria to prevent it from running when the line in the file is correct...if the line in the file is wrong it work because it replaces it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the line is "bad"? Which cases do you want to cover? The correct IP, but with a wrong hostname?

Comment: yes or vice-verza.. correct hostname with wrong IP. I belive the regexes are OK  i tested them on regex101.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem with lineinfile, it's not that useful as it looks.

My advice: load file content into variable (`- command: cat /etc/hosts`), register it (`register: old_hosts`) than iterate over each line of that variable in a template.

```
- name: get hosts
  command: cat /etc/hosts
  register: old_hosts
- name: write hosts
  template:
  src: hosts.j2
  dest: /etc/hosts
```

hosts.j2:

```
{% for line in old_hosts.stdout_lines %}
{% if line (....) %}
  ... 
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```